# Can't expose Graylog web interface on public IP address using Linux Azure VM

Tags: graylog

I am following [this guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-graylog-on-ubuntu-16-04.html) to setup Graylog on Linux Azure VM instance.
It suggests:

> `sudo nano /etc/graylog/server/server.conf`
>
> Update the below entry with
> your system ip address from which you will access the Graylog web
> interface.
>
> `http_bind_address = your-server-ip:9000`

But I am failing to do so, when I set value to `40.112.69.234:9000` (i am fine with exposing IP), Graylog refuses to start

```
2021-02-07T17:07:33.967Z ERROR [ServerBootstrap] Graylog startup failed. Exiting. Exception was:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be healthy after starting. The following services are not running: {FAILED=[JerseyService [FAILED]]}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager$ServiceManagerState.checkHealthy(ServiceManager.java:741) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager$ServiceManagerState.awaitHealthy(ServiceManager.java:553) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.awaitHealthy(ServiceManager.java:314) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at org.graylog2.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.startCommand(ServerBootstrap.java:148) [graylog.jar:?]
        at org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool.run(CmdLineTool.java:210) [graylog.jar:?]
        at org.graylog2.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:50) [graylog.jar:?]
        Suppressed: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager$FailedService: JerseyService [FAILED]
        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:238) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:218) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:209) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener.start(NetworkListener.java:723) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:277) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.graylog2.shared.initializers.JerseyService.startUpApi(JerseyService.java:196) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at org.graylog2.shared.initializers.JerseyService.startUp(JerseyService.java:142) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119) ~[graylog.jar:?]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
2021-02-07T17:07:33.972Z INFO  [Server] SIGNAL received. Shutting down.
```

I tried keeping default value of `127.0.0.1:9000`, it looks like service is running ok, but I can't reach web interface from outside, only via `curl`. How do I make Graylog accessible on the public IP? Will be glad to share more details if needed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Create selinux or apparmor module (or disable it, but not an advice).

Answer (score 0):

Add your external IP address as the value for:

*http_external_uri =*